# why not pass the data in success function (Ajax)

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'll try to pass id into controller function.But there was problem. using my image i think can get idea. So I want to know why this data didn't pass the success function.

[image: Please give me the hint.]

Comment: There's probably some error in the url you've mentioned. Have you tried Chrome debugger to check out what went wrong?

Comment: yes sir.i used the Chrome debugger.I want to know why data = "  " like this.why data not set to success function

Comment: Use inspect element and go to Network tab. It will show the requested AJAX URL. Open it on another tab and see what it shows. Seems like it's facing an error.